# Image is jumping before animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I currently have an image animating on the click of a button, but the problem is that the image is jumping from it's position on the storyboard before it starts the animation. I cannot figure out why it's doing this - all I would like to do it move it from its current position off the screen to the right.

Am I doing something wrong, or just missing something?

**Original position:**

[image: original]

**Beginning of animation:**

[image: original]

**moveImage trigger:**

```
[self moveImage:_cornerCloud duration:3.0
              curve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear x:200.0 y:0];
```

**moveImage function:**

```
- (void)moveImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
        curve:(int)curve x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y
{

// Setup the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

// The transform matrix
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
image.transform = transform;

// Commit the changes
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: You should be using `[UIView animateWithDuration:...];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                  // just set the center to off-screen
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

That should be a bit easier.